# Сканирование букв через input

Tags: java

Создаю не большой проект, задумка такая: есть список фильмов, случайным образом выбирается один фильм из списка и каждая буква закрывается знаком "_" Пользователю показывается скрытое название и он начинает угадывать зашифрованное слово по одной букве.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("name.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean hasWon = false;

    String[] filmName = {"the shawshank redemption", "the godfather", "the dark knight", "schindler's list", "pulp fiction", "the lord of the rings", "the good the bad and the ugly", "fight club", "the lord of the rings", "forrest gump", "star wars", "inception", "the lord of the rings", "the matrix", "samurai", "star wars", "city of god", "the silence of the lambs", "batman begins", "die hard", "chinatown", "room", "dunkirk", "fargo", "no country for old men"};
    // randomly select an index from the arr
    int select = random.nextInt(filmName.length);
    // prints out a value of a randomly selected index
    System.out.println(filmName[select]);

    // replacing characters by underscore
    String _result = filmName[select];
    _result = _result.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z_0-9]", "_"); // replace each letter with _
    System.out.println(_result);

    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) { //shows a count of remaining opportunities
        System.out.println("You have " + i + " attempts. Keep going.");


        //тут должен быть код, который поочередно открывает каждую угаданную букву пользователем, постепенно открывая слово
        String buildRegex = "";
        Scanner scannerinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String chars = scannerinput.nextLine();
        buildRegex.replaceAll("_", "[chars]");


        boolean[] lettersGuessed = new boolean[26];
        int guessed = 0;
        // Make sure the guess is a letter
        if (guessed <= 0 && guessed <= 25) {
            if (lettersGuessed[guessed]) {
                // The user already guessed this letter, do nothing
            } else {
                lettersGuessed[guessed] = true;
                // See if the letter guessed was right, if it was show the letters
                // If it wasn't, incorrectGuesses+1
            }

            boolean correct = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < chars.length(); j++) {
                if (lettersGuessed.equals(chars)) {
                    correct = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (filmName[select].equals(chars)) {
            hasWon = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasWon) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations!");
        System.out.println("You have guessed the film!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You lose!");
        System.out.println("The film was " + filmName[select] + ".");
    }
}
```

Все работает кроме по буквенного угадывания. Если ввести название полностью, то срабатывает

> if (filmName[select].equals(chars)) {
>                   hasWon = true;

но если вводить по одной букве, то просто считает сколько попыток осталось до полного угадывания слова, не открывая буквы. ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы вводите по 1 букве, то это условие `if (filmName[select].equals(chars))` выполнится только в том случае, если имя фильма состоит из 1 буквы и вы её угадали.

Замечу, что вы даете только 10 попыток и всегда их вычитаете. Т.е. угадать фильм в названии которого больше 10 букв невозможно.

В этом условии вы кажется ошиблись знаком `if (guessed <= 0 && guessed <= 25)`

---

Тут вы пытаетесь сравнить массив `boolean` с массивом `char` это сравнение всегда будет давать false. Плюс вы делаете его столько раз, сколько букв в массиве `chars`, т.е. много раз повторяете одно действие (которое никогда не выполнится).

```
for (int j = 0; j < chars.length(); j++) {
    if (lettersGuessed.equals(chars)) {
       correct = true;
    }
}
```

---

Ну и последнее, что увидел:

```
    buildRegex.replaceAll("_", "[chars]");
```

тут вы пытаетесь заменить все нижние подчеркивания на "[chars]". Не на символы массива, а на слова "[chars]"

Т.е. было слово `inception`, заменили на `_________`.

Командой выше получили `[chars][chars][chars][chars][chars][chars][chars][chars][chars]`